# AG-Grid (Community) : Preventing Client Side Sorting

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I got server-side search/pagination/sort working just fine.

However, in the second or so before the new results are received back from the server and loaded in the grid, the grid will perform its default client-side sorting.

Is it possible to "cancel" the default behavior of the `sortChanged` event?

`(sortChanged)="onSortChanged($event)"`

```
  onSortChanged(event) {
    const sortState = this.gridApi.getSortModel();
    if (sortState.length === 1) {
      const sortDirection = sortState[0].sort;
      const sortColumn = sortState[0].colId;
      this.sortingChanged.emit({ sortDirection, sortColumn });  // this will trigger the server side search method in the parent component
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had to add a comparer to prevent client side  sorting

```
  {
    headerName: 'Date',
    field: 'date',
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    comparator: () => 0    ///custom sorting comparator returns the same data
  },
```